# How to code ordinary least squares linear regression for a 3D scatterplot in Python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

This is for a 3D scatterplot.
The instructions state:
Now that we have fit our model, which means that we have computed the optimal model parameters, we can use our model to plot the regression line for the data. Below, I supply you with `x_fit` and `y_fit` that represent the x- and y-data of the regression line, respectively. All we need to do next is ask the model to predict a `z_fit` value for each `x_fit` and `y_fit` pair by invoking the model's **`predict()`** method. This should make sense when you consider the ordinary least squares linear regression equation for calculating `z_fit`:

[image]

where  [image]  are the computed model parameters. You must use `x_fit` and `y_fit` as features to be passed together as a DataFrame to the model's predict() method, which will return `z_fit` as determined by the above equation. Once you obtain `z_fit`, you are ready to plot the regression line by plotting it against `x_fit` and `y_fit`.
My code so far is:

```
features = df[['x', 'y']]
response = df['z']

#perform linear regression model fitting

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression().fit(features, response)
model


print("Model Coefficients: ", model.coef_)
print("Model Intercept : ", model.intercept_)
```

Output:

```
Model Coefficients:  [ 8.02602396 15.95639323]
Model Intercept :  -8.632876775060822
```

This is where I'm stuck:

```
# Plot Curve Fit
x_fit = np.linspace(0,21,1000)
y_fit = x_fit

#ENTER CODE HERE#
```

Comment: Can you format the equation? It would make it easy to understand.

Comment: I made the changes for the equation. I hope that helps.

Comment: This might help. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Plot Curve Fit
x_fit = np.linspace(0,21,1000)
y_fit = x_fit

#ENTER CODE HERE#
```

Assuming

```
theta1, theta2 = model.coef_
theta3 = model.intercept_
```

Equation

```
z_fit = (theta1 * x_fit) + (theta2 * y_fit) + theta3
```

Comment: As the instruction states, I have to "ask the model to predict a z_fit value for each x_fit and y_fit pair by invoking the model's `predict()` method"